# Magento 2 Sort by new from date and price ascending

Tags: magento2, sort-by-options, sortby

I want to sort the product collections with new from date and low to high price within a loaded collections. For eg, low to high price should to be displayed to the new products (new from date) first and then remaining products.

It's not working when I use both attributes.

- Method1:

  ```
  $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc')->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
  ```
- Method2:

  ```
  $subject->getCollection()->setOrder(array('news_from_date desc', 'price asc'));
  ```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
$collection->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')->setOrder('price', 'asc');
```

or

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("news_from_date desc, price asc"));
```

In case Zend dont work, you should add this first to be able used the \Zend_DB_Expr on the news_from_date and price.

```
->addAttributeToSelect('news_from_date', 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('price', 'left')
```

Comment: yes, i tried the above methods not working

Comment: Did you mean this $subject->getCollection()->setOrder(array('news_from_date desc', 'price asc')); ? This wont work since your argumetns is an array and the setOrder method only accept 2 arguments which is strings ..

Comment: not getting expected results when using ->addAttributeToSelect('news_from_date', 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('price', 'left')

Comment: did you check that you got values from news_from_date and price ??

Comment: if I use that separately it works fine. when we combine both attributes it's not working as expected. I need to display price low to high in all new  from date products

Comment: do you have any other idea to implement?

Comment: Is above code compatible with magento 2.4.2? Can you please help to fix this issue.

Comment: `$collection->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')->setOrder('price', 'asc'); ` I'm using that on my projects and it also working on version 2.4.1 enterprise. so can you double check or log its raw sql query .. maybe its has something we dont know.

Comment: and on your post you are using **addAttributeToSort** so can you try change it to **setOrder** instead ? and your method 1 and method 2 are not same, on method1 you prioritize the the price but on method2 your are using the news_from_date at first.. so possible your issue is only typo. Also it seems method will not actually work since the **setOrder** only accepting 2 string arguments.

Comment: Getting the price ascending collections only not new from date If I use below

if ($currentOrder == 'news_from_date') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('news_from_date', 'desc')->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }

Comment: _$currentOrder == 'news_from_date')_ have you check this if there is a $currentOrder value news_from_date ?? maybe your code was not loaded because of the conditions.

Comment: yes I can set default order is 'news_from_date'  by using 

public function beforeSetDefaultOrder(
                \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
            )
    {
    
    return ['news_from_date'];
    }

Comment: so can you check if what the raw sql ? by using `$subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString();`

Comment: having product collections instead of getting raw sql

Comment: have you tried log it? or `echo $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString(); die();` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134784/discussion-between-mahikam-and-).